# What is the appropriate javafx 8 panel?

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I have a tabpane and in of the tabs i need to have a layout where i have four sub-windows (panes ?) which should have the controls to maximize and minimize.
Maximize (may be twice of its original size), it should not take the entire window size, it should be relative to the tab it is part of. which panel would be the most appropriate for  this use case ?[image]

Comment: There's probably many ways to do it; you might just have to try to see which works best. My first guess would be a grid pane; you can maximize by setting the row and column index to 0 and the row and column span to the total number of rows and columns, and then calling `toFront()`. To restore to original size, set the row and column index to their original and the row and column span to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one suggestion, using a `GridPane` and maximizing the content from one "cell" by manipulating the row and column index and row and column span.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExpandingPanes extends Application {

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane tabs = new TabPane();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 4 ; i++) {
            final String tabText = "Tab "+ i ;
            tabs.getTabs().add(new Tab(tabText, createGridPane(x -> tabText+" : Pane "+x, 2, 2)));
        }
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tabs);
        root.setBottom(new TextField());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private GridPane createGridPane(IntFunction<String> labelText, int numRows, int numCols) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        for (int row = 0 ; row < numRows; row++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setFillHeight(true);
            rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            rc.setPercentHeight(100.0 / numRows);
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }
        for (int col = 0 ; col < numCols; col++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setFillWidth(true);
            cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            cc.setPercentWidth(100.0 / numCols);
            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < numRows * numCols; i++) {
            int row = i / numRows ;
            int col = i % numCols ;
            Pane tile = createPane(col, row, numCols, numRows, labelText.apply(i));
            grid.add(tile, col, row);
        }

        return grid ;
    }

    private Pane createPane(int col, int row, int numCols, int numRows, String text) {
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane();
        content.setCenter(new Label(text));
        ToggleButton maximize = new ToggleButton();
        maximize.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(maximize.selectedProperty()).then("Restore").otherwise("Maximize"));
        maximize.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasMax, isNowMax) -> {
           if (isNowMax) {
               GridPane.setColumnIndex(content, 0);
               GridPane.setRowIndex(content, 0);
               GridPane.setColumnSpan(content, numCols);
               GridPane.setRowSpan(content, numRows);
               content.toFront();
           } else {
               GridPane.setColumnIndex(content, col);
               GridPane.setRowIndex(content, row);
               GridPane.setColumnSpan(content, 1);
               GridPane.setRowSpan(content, 1);
           }
        });
        BorderPane.setMargin(maximize, new Insets(5));
        BorderPane.setAlignment(maximize, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        content.setTop(maximize);

        content.setStyle(randomColor());

        return content ;
    }

    private String randomColor() {
        return String.format("-fx-background-color: -fx-background; -fx-background: rgb(%d, %d, %d);", 
                rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what the question asks for. What if i want to show the maximized pane as a dialog box ? any ideas

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. If you want to show a dialog box, just show a dialog box.

Comment: when I said dialog, I meant maximize like a pop-up instead of covering the entire tab space